# Create new form fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I have a form which starts out with 2 text inputs. The standard scenario is the user enters a number in one field and his/her name in the other and then the page will be updated (not reloaded). But in some cases the user may want to enter several numbers which are connected to the same name and the way this will be implemented is by the user clicking an "add another" link next to the text box.

When the user clicks the "add another" link, the value from the textbox needs to be inserted into a new (dynamically created) text field and the text field where the user entered the number should be reset to default value. The user can enter 10 numbers this way before an alert is presented informing him/her about more efficient ways to do this operation.

I'm clueless as to how this is done (can it be done) jQuery and it would be great if someone can help out.

Here is the html I'm working with:

```
<div id="searchFields" class="control-group inlineForm">
    <label for="regNr">Regnr</label> <input type="text" id="regNr" class="uprCase" placeholder="Regnr." size="6" maxlength="6">
    <span class="addRegNr"><a href="#">add another</a></div>
    <label for="poNr">PO.nr</label> <input type="text" id="poNr" placeholder="PO.nr." size="12" maxlength="12">
    <input type="button" value="GET INFO" class="last" id="getBaseInf">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RgKV9/

Cheers!

**EDIT UPDATE**

I've taken a liking to Aske G's example and have made some changes to it. Here is the new code I'm working with, [jsfiddle.net/SDpfy](http://jsfiddle.net/SDpfy) Although I managed to do some minor changes to AskeG's code I cant figure out how to add unique ID's and individual delete links for each generated field that ends up in the basket. Also, how can I set the generated fields to readonly and animate them when they show up in the basket?

Comment: -->EDIT UPDATE 2! I've been looking at all the good examples and have taken bits and pieces from a few of them and managed to get almost all desired functionality now but I'm stuck on how to get the links which are supposed to delete a field to delete the field it is connected to. Have a look here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tbfHF/1/) and my explanation will hopefully become clearer.

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/2YG5P/ just add another listener to the delete button and do your jQuery there.

Comment: does not work for me the jsfiddle you link to. I've managed to get everything together here: http://jsfiddle.net/KYkJn/10/

Answer (score 0):

just add a click watcher to the span. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith19/RgKV9/4/

I have done some basic changes. If you need custom names id's you should use a templating library and then append it

```
<div id="searchFields" class="control-group inlineForm">
    <label for="regNr">Regnr</label> <input type="text" id="regNr" class="uprCase" placeholder="Regnr." size="6"
                                            maxlength="6">

    <label for="poNr">PO.nr</label> <input type="text" id="poNr" placeholder="PO.nr." size="12" maxlength="12">
    <input type="button" value="GET INFO" class="last" id="getBaseInf">

    <p></p>
</div>
<span class="addRegNr" style="display:inline"><a href="#">add another</a></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        str_to_append = '<label for="regNr">Regnr</label> <input type="text" id="regNr" class="uprCase" placeholder="Regnr." size="6" maxlength="6">\
    <label for="poNr">PO.nr</label> <input type="text" id="poNr" placeholder="PO.nr." size="12" maxlength="12">\
    <input type="button" value="GET INFO" class="last" id="getBaseInf"><p></p>'
        $(".addRegNr").click(function () {
            $("#searchFields").append(str_to_append)
        })
    })

</script>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, using jquery append method.

here I leave a link with some examples:

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you might just be looking for  [something like this](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<div id="searchFields" class="control-group inlineForm">
<label for="regNr">Regnr&nbsp;</label><input type="text" id="regNr" class="uprCase" placeholder="Regnr." size="6" maxlength="6"/><br/>
</div>
<span class="addRegNr">add another</span><br/>
<label for="poNr">PO.nr</label> <input type="text" id="poNr" placeholder="PO.nr." size="12" maxlength="12">
<input type="button" value="GET INFO" class="last" id="getBaseInf">
```

and then some js that looked like this:

```
var $input = $("#searchFields").children();

$(".addRegNr").on("click", function(){
   var $newField = $input.clone();
   // change what you need to do with the field here.
   $(this).siblings("#searchFields").append($newField);
});
```

It's also here: http://jsfiddle.net/tatLw/

Comment: Thx everyone, great replies! I like this approach, I found it easy to modify and have done so here: http://jsfiddle.net/SDpfy/. But am wondering how I can add a delete link next to each field that ends up in the basket. Also, how can I add unique id to the fields, and for flair some animation effect when the field appears in the basket?

Comment: fields get's unique id's in the comment I gave on your post, check source-code. Animations can be done by jquery's .animate().

Answer (score 0):

To add any HTML with jQuery you will eventually end up calling [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), or one of its variations like [.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/), [.appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), etc.

These can be given raw HTML strings, but unless you have an HTML template ready and plain, don't use string concatenation to build your HTM. This is fragile and insecure. Instead, create the elements with [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) directly, like so:

```
jQuery('<input type="text"/>').attr({
    value: '',
    placeholder: '...',
    id: '..'
})
.appendTo( .. )
```

In addition, don't forget to create labels for these new elements as well (if appropiate).

Another few best practices relevant to this scenario:

- If you're going to be dynamically making new form elements appear (as opposed to adding more additional fields for an existing field), it is best to not create these with JavaScript. Instead make sure they are present in the page output from the beginning, then hide them from `$(document).ready` with [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). That way it will be a lot easier (as all you need is a reference to the hidden element, and call .show() when you have to). And that way it doesn't rely on javascript flow being present, enabled and functioning as expected because this way if anything happened along the way (exception thrown, cdn issues, whatever) the form will fallback to a fully-present version that just works.
- If you're going to have a lot of these "+" or "add" button scenarios, I'd make a [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) of the original field, strip it (clear value, remove id-attribute), and store it in a local variable. Then from the click handler, clone that, and put it into the document where you need it. You may also want to have a server-side fallback by making the add button a submit button with a certain name/value pair that the server detects as a non-final input in which case it will return the same page with the values pre-filled but with more fields.

Answer (score 0):

Basing solution on this blog post [jQuery – Dynamically Adding Form Elements](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/) by [Charlie Griefer](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/about-charlie/), you could try the following:

**Markup**:

```
<div id="searchFields" class="control-group inlineForm">
<form id="myForm">
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        <label for="regNr">Regnr</label>: <input type="text" name="regNr" placeholder="Regnr." size="6" maxlength="6" />
        <label for="poNr">PO.nr</label>: <input type="text" id="poNr" placeholder="PO.nr." size="12" maxlength="12">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another Reg field" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove fields" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="GET INFO" class="last" id="getBaseInf">
</form>
</div>​
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value  
    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

    // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
    newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'regNr' + newNum).attr('regNr', 'regNr' + newNum);

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

    // enable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');

    // business rule: you can only add 5 names
    if (newNum == 5)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
});


$('#btnDel').click(function() {
     var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

    $('#input' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled',''); // enable the "add" button

    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if (num-1 == 1)
          $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
});

$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');​
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/qW9ra/