# how to do multiple form submissions in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, submit

A user/admin logins and register students as many as he want.After clicking on Finish we need to provide 
payment options then after selecting we need to generate registration numbers to all students and all students must have same payment option selected at the end.

My Question is How to hold form values of each student(contain nearly 100 fields) till he click on finish and how to insert and generate reg no to all these students

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY to edit the html in place, adding as many additional fields as necessary. For each new student, increment an ID number in the field name. Submit all the information on one form, then just parse out the results.

This post talks about how to use jquery to add form fields: [Create new form fields with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011718/create-new-form-fields-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

For an admin section you could try:

```
session_start(['username']);

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{

$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("login");

$POST = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($POST))
{
    $admin = $row['account'];
}

if ($admin ==0)
die("You're not an admin <a href='member.php'>Main menu</a>");



}
else
            die("You must be logged in <a href='index.php'>Back</a>");
?>
```

Add account as one of your database column tables.

This is a useful tutorial to follow:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65gV8JOgWkQ&list=PL149E761860153CC8

Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `account` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;
```

Registration form:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['forename'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['surname'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['repassword']))
    {
    $errors = array();
    //form data
    $forename = strip_tags($_POST['forename']);
    $username = strtolower(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
    $surname = strip_tags($_POST['surname']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $repassword = strip_tags($_POST['repassword']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    //connect to database
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("login");

    $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

    if (empty ($forename) || empty($email)){
    $errors[] ='All fields are required';
    }else{
    if(strlen($forename) >25 || strlen($forename) <3) {
    $errors[] = 'Your forename must be at least three letters long and a maximum of twenty letters';
    }
        if ($count!=0)
        {
    $errors[] = 'Username already taken';
    }
    if(strlen($surname) >25 || strlen($surname) <3) {
    $errors[] = 'Your surname must be at least three letters long and a maximum of twenty letters';
    }
    if(strlen($username) >25 || strlen($username) <3) {
    $errors[] = 'Your username must be at least three letters long and a maximum of twenty letters';
    }
    if(strlen($password) >25 || strlen($password) <3) {
    $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least three letters long and a maximum of twenty letters';
    }
    if(($password) != ($repassword)) {
    $errors[] = 'Your passwords do not match ';
    }
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ===FALSE) {
    $errors[] ='Please enter a valid email';
    }

    }
    if(!empty($errors)){

    foreach ($errors as $errors){
    echo '<strong>',$errors ,'</strong><br />';
    }
    }else{

    $password = md5($password);
    $repassword = md5($repassword);

    $queryreg = mysql_query ("

    INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$forename','$surname','$email','$password','$username','')
    ");
    header("Refresh: 1; url=index.php");
    die("you have registered <a href=index.php>Login</a>") ;
    }

    }
?>


<form action =""  method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Forename:</td><td><input type="text" name="forename" value='<?php if (isset($_POST['forename'])) echo $forename; ?>'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Surname:</td><td><input type="text" name="surname" value='<?php if (isset($_POST['surname'])) echo $surname; ?>'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type='text' name='username' value='<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) echo $username; ?>'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email:<td><input type ="text" name="email" value='<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $email; ?>'/><td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Repeat password:</td><td><input type='password' name='repassword'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Register"/></td></tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

Login:

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$errors = array();


if ($username&&$password)
{

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db ("login") or die ("Could not find database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows !=0)
{
    while ($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }

    if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
    {
        echo header( 'Location: member.php' ) ;
        $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
        $_SESSION['userid']=$userid;
    }
    else 
        //echo "Inncorrect password";
    echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
              var text = document.createTextNode('Mmm ... something');
                document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', textchange1);

            </script>
        ";
     }  

}
else
    die("That user dosen't exist");

}

else
    die("Please enter a username and a password");



if(isset($_POST['btn'])){


?>
```

Username: 
        Password: 
        
        Register

Comment: Thanks for the Link.My requirement is similar to the link provided.But instead of items the admin register students and all students should get individual reg no at end with payment option selected at end.Can you provide any sample code

Comment: That's quite a large project, off hand I could give you a sample code of registration and login although you would need to do someone work to prevent sql injection to it.

Comment: What's this `session_start(['username']);`? `bool session_start ( void )` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: That's the way we were taught where I study, it sets the session name as far as we were told.

Comment: Not by what [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) states `bool session_start ( void )`. Void means "nothing/empty".